# R remove rows with NA in groups of columns containing the same string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains multiple variables each measured with multiple items at two different time points. What I want to remove all rows with NA entries in groups of columns containing the same part of a string. Some of these groups contain multiple columns (e.g., `grep("learn")`, some only one (e.g., `T1_age`. This is my original dataframe (a part of it):

```
data <- data.frame(
      T1_age = c(39, 30, 20, 48, 27, 55, 37, 50, 50, 37),
      T1_sex = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1),
   T2_learn1 = c(2, NA, 3, 4, 1, NA, NA, 2, 4, 4),
   T2_learn2 = c(1, NA, 4, 4, 1, NA, NA, 2, 4, 4),
   T2_learn3 = c(2, NA, 4, 4, 1, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4),
   T2_learn4 = c(2, NA, 2, 5, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5),
   T2_learn5 = c(4, NA, 3, 4, 3, NA, NA, 3, 4, 3),
     T2_aut1 = c(NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, 4),
     T2_aut2 = c(NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5),
     T2_aut3 = c(NA, NA, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5),
    T2_ssup1 = c(1, NA, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, 2, 4, 3),
    T2_ssup2 = c(3, NA, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4),
    T2_ssup3 = c(4, NA, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4),
    T2_ssup4 = c(2, NA, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4),
   T3_learn1 = c(3, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4),
   T3_learn2 = c(1, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4),
   T3_learn3 = c(3, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 5),
   T3_learn4 = c(4, NA, NA, 5, 4, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5),
   T3_learn5 = c(4, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4),
     T3_aut1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5),
     T3_aut2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5),
     T3_aut3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5),
    T3_ssup1 = c(3, NA, NA, 5, 4, NA, NA, 2, 4, 1),
    T3_ssup2 = c(3, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5),
    T3_ssup3 = c(4, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 3),
    T3_ssup4 = c(3, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 4)
)
```

Now I already found a very horrible solution and I believe that could be improved. So this code basically does what I want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data %>% filter(rowSums(is.na(.[ , grep("learn", colnames(.))])) != ncol(.[ , grep("learn", colnames(.))]))
data <- data %>% filter(rowSums(is.na(.[ , grep("aut", colnames(.))])) != ncol(.[ , grep("aut", colnames(.))]))
data <- data %>% filter(rowSums(is.na(.[ , grep("ssup", colnames(.))])) != ncol(.[ , grep("ssup", colnames(.))]))
data <- data %>% drop_na(T1_age)
data <- data %>% drop_na(T1_sex)
```

So the new data frame (and what I want to achieve) looks like this:

```
data2 <- data.frame(
      T1_age = c(20, 48, 27, 50, 50, 37),
      T1_sex = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
   T2_learn1 = c(3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4),
   T2_learn2 = c(4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4),
   T2_learn3 = c(4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4),
   T2_learn4 = c(2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
   T2_learn5 = c(3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3),
     T2_aut1 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4),
     T2_aut2 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5),
     T2_aut3 = c(4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5),
    T2_ssup1 = c(4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3),
    T2_ssup2 = c(4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4),
    T2_ssup3 = c(4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4),
    T2_ssup4 = c(3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4),
   T3_learn1 = c(NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4),
   T3_learn2 = c(NA, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4),
   T3_learn3 = c(NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5),
   T3_learn4 = c(NA, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5),
   T3_learn5 = c(NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4),
     T3_aut1 = c(NA, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5),
     T3_aut2 = c(NA, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5),
     T3_aut3 = c(NA, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5),
    T3_ssup1 = c(NA, 5, 4, 2, 4, 1),
    T3_ssup2 = c(NA, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5),
    T3_ssup3 = c(NA, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3),
    T3_ssup4 = c(NA, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4)
        )
```

Could you help me improve this a bit? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may iterate over `grep` in an `sapply` and check if the `rowSums` in the slices reach their number of columns.

```
V <- c('learn', 'aut', 'ssup')

res <- data[!rowSums(sapply(V, \(v) {
  X <- data[grep(v, names(data))]
  rowSums(is.na(X)) == dim(X)[2]
})), ]

stopifnot(all.equal(res, data2, check.attributes=FALSE))
```

Or probably just checking if the sums of `NA`'s in the "hot" columns reach the number of columns (without the demographics) is enough.

```
res1 <- data[rowSums(is.na(data[grep(paste(V, collapse='|'), names(data))])) != 
               dim(data[-(1:2)])[2], ]

stopifnot(all.equal(res1, data2, check.attributes=FALSE))
```

`data2` is the result data frame you provide in OP. `dim(data)[2]` gives the same as `ncol(data)`.

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`

Comment: Hi, I think this could be a useful approach. The second solution does not work because it removes all rows where all columns are NA. That is not what I want. I want to have a data frame where rows are removed if all columns ```grep("learn")``` are missing or all columns ```grep("ssup")```  are missing and so on. For the first solution I get an error ```Error: unexpected input in "res <- data[!rowSums(sapply(V, \"``` Maybe this should look a bit different?

Comment: @Ane I'm sure you're using an old R version. Since R 4.1, instead of `function(x)` it's now also possible to write `\(x)`. You could replace all ```\``` with `function`, but I recommend to to   [update R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/) anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I will definitely do that. For now, I substituted all ```\\``` with ```function```. That works. I updated the example to illustrate the problem a bit better (updated the dataframe - now row one has ```NA``` for all ```grep("aut")``` columns). The issue is that your functions still give me 7 rows (with the updated dataframe), while I want 6 rows (using the ugly code I posted in the original question, that works!)

Comment: @Ane I edited the code of first version, it should generalize better now. Does that work for you? (And don't call your code ugly, let's say it is a bit raw and can be refined:)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I added ```%>% drop_na(T1_age, T1_sex)``` to also drop the single column NAs

Comment: Welcome @Ane , glad to help.